# onclick event of google app script not working

Tags: google-apps-script

some days before my code working fine with

`"onclick='google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)"` but suddenly its stop working without any changes in code.

***mycode:***

**html file:-**

```
<form id='addnewForm' action='myurl' method="post"> 
     <input name='name' type="text" >
     <input name='age' type='text'> 

<input type='submit'  value="submit" name="submit" onclick='google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)' >

 </form>
```

**code.js file:**

```
    function processForm(value) {


      var  name= value.name;
      var  age= value.age;

 Logger.log('name is: ' + name);
  Logger.log('age is:' + age);

    }
```

Before processForm function give output but now its not giving any output neither its calling.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, please *star* this [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1660) to keep track of updates.